# Azure DevOps Pipeline build failure

Tags: java, azure, pipeline

I am trying to build a Pipeline job in Azure DevOps. However, the build failed for the following reasons:
Failed tests:   runCukes(cucumbertest.TestRunner_web): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: C:\chromedriver.exe

The test is running successfully in my local machine. But it is not running in Azure DevOps due to the above error.
Please let me know how to fix that

Comment: I'm betting that it's just not installed in that location on the VM running the Azure Pipelines Agent. Is the agent on a VM of yours, or is it Microsoft-hosted?

Comment: The agent is Microsoft hosted. Is there any way to tackle this issue please?